# Merge sort continues calling itself, despite condition

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I'm having an awful strange problem, teaching myself to write sorts.
I've made this merge sort with Python.

I'm wondering if you could help me understand why this continues to call itself, despite the condition to close the function being met.

```
print arrayToSort 
#[[67], [26], [75], [80], [54], [93], [97], [96], [77], [91]]

def merge_sort(array):
    newTotalArray = []
    for x in range(0, len(array)/2):
        newSubArray = []
        lowerX = x*2
        upperX = x*2+1
        while len(array[lowerX]) > 0 or len(array[upperX]) > 0:
            if len(array[lowerX]) > 0 and len(array[upperX]) > 0:
                if array[lowerX][0] <= array[upperX][0]:
                    newSubArray.append(array[lowerX][0])
                    del array[lowerX][0]
                else:
                    newSubArray.append(array[upperX][0])
                    del array[upperX][0]
            elif len(array[lowerX]) > 0:
                newSubArray.append(array[lowerX][0])
                del array[lowerX][0]
            else:
                newSubArray.append(array[upperX][0])
                del array[upperX][0]
        newTotalArray.append(newSubArray)
    if len(array) % 2 != 0:
        newTotalArray.append(array[len(array)-1])
    print 'still going'
    print newTotalArray
    if len(newTotalArray) > 1:
        merge_sort(newTotalArray)
    print 'finished'
    print newTotalArray

merge_sort(arrayToSort)
```

I expected this function to stop calling itself when len(newTotalArray) == 1.

But, for this code I get

```
[[67], [26], [75], [80], [54], [93], [97], [96], [77], [91]]
still going
[[26, 67], [75, 80], [54, 93], [96, 97], [77, 91]]
still going
[[26, 67, 75, 80], [54, 93, 96, 97], [77, 91]]
still going
[[26, 54, 67, 75, 80, 93, 96, 97], [77, 91]]
still going
[[26, 54, 67, 75, 77, 80, 91, 93, 96, 97]]
finished
[[26, 54, 67, 75, 77, 80, 91, 93, 96, 97]]
finished
[[], []]
finished
[[], [], []]
finished
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

I need to put this in module and return the result, but if I do so the result is `[[], [], [], [], []]`

Could you please help me understand why this occurs?

Comment: It's not continuing, it's essentially unwrapping itself from all previous recursive calls. It probably helps it you can move the stop condition near the top of your function, because then all those "unwrapping" steps don't do anything (`if len(array) < 2: return`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python modifies lists in place instead of a copy of a list (this is pass by reference as opposed to pass by value).  Thus, each time that you delete an entry, you are removing it from your original list, and thus the one you are left with.  It isn't still calling, it is just finishing up the previous value.  The extra "empty" arrays are from the print statement at the end as opposed to the one before it.  The fact that these have the same length as the provided arrays, but are empty, is what tells you that this deletion is happening on the original array.

For example:

```
def mess_with_array(array):
    for i in range(2,len(array)):
        del array[2]

test = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
mess_with_array(test)
print test
```

results in [1,2].  This is because we have modified the original array.

The trick is to either return values (if you don't care about the original array), or to work with a copy and return values.

Change

```
if len(newTotalArray) > 1:
    merge_sort(newTotalArray)
```

to

```
if len(newTotalArray) > 1:
    return merge_sort(newTotalArray)
else: return newTotalArray
```

and run the function with

```
arrayToSort = merge_sort(arrayToSort)
```

or if you wish to work with copies and preserve the original array, call with

```
sortedArray = merge_sort(arrayToSort[:])
```

This pass by reference vs pass by value issue is subtle and it will bite you pretty bad if you aren't careful.  The first thing I look for when dealing with a new language is what sort of passing it does.

One extra tip (and how I figured out what was going wrong).  When working with recursive functions, add a "calls" parameter with a default value of 0, and pass it to the function incremented by one each time, and provide it in all print statements - this allows you to see which statements are from each call, and lets you see that the function is unwrapping at the end.

Comment: I made the changes and they work. I don't fully understand yet but will do my reading. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your "finished" statement is reached multiple times in error. A simple fix is to return control out of your recursive function before it reaches that line. Insert the `return` keyword in this if block:-

```
if len(newTotalArray) > 1:
    merge_sort(newTotalArray)
    return
```

Incidentally, code like `array[len(array)-1]` offends me. Please use this form instead:-

```
if len(array) % 2 != 0:
    newTotalArray.append(array[-1])
```

One final thought. Recursion is to be avoided as it is *expensive* at run time in terms of memory used. Removing elements from the start of an array using the `del array[0]` keyword is also less efficient than deleting the last element. Here is a simpler merge sort implementation in Python which avoids recursion and also avoids *always* removing the first element in the temporary lists:-

```
def merge_sort(array):
    print 'Original: ', array
    array = map(lambda x: [x], array)
    print 'Nested: ', array
    while len(array) > 1:
        for i in xrange(len(array)-2,-1,-2):
            newArray = []
            arrayA, indexA = array[i], 0
            arrayB, indexB = array[i+1], 0
            while indexA < len(arrayA) and indexB < len(arrayB):
                if arrayA[indexA] < arrayB[indexB]:
                    newArray.append(arrayA[indexA])
                    indexA += 1
                else:
                    newArray.append(arrayB[indexB])
                    indexB += 1
            if indexA < len(arrayA):
                newArray += arrayA[indexA:]
            if indexB < len(arrayB):
                newArray += arrayB[indexB:]
            array[i] = newArray
            del array[i+1]
        print 'Step: ', array
    return array[0]

arrayToSort = [93, 64, 16, 28, 65, 80, 42, 96, 8, 44, 1]
print merge_sort( arrayToSort )
#Original:  [93, 64, 16, 28, 65, 80, 42, 96, 8, 44, 1]
#Nested:  [[93], [64], [16], [28], [65], [80], [42], [96], [8], [44], [1]]
#Step:  [[93], [16, 64], [28, 65], [42, 80], [8, 96], [1, 44]]
#Step:  [[16, 64, 93], [28, 42, 65, 80], [1, 8, 44, 96]]
#Step:  [[16, 64, 93], [1, 8, 28, 42, 44, 65, 80, 96]]
#Step:  [[1, 8, 16, 28, 42, 44, 64, 65, 80, 93, 96]]

#[1, 8, 16, 28, 42, 44, 64, 65, 80, 93, 96]
```

Comment: I just ran some tests, iteration certainly seems much faster. For lists of 64,000 elems, over 20 tests, your function ran an average of 1.7 seconds per test compared to 3.9 for my original function.